# Cycle in directed graph in prolog

Tags: prolog

I created a program in prolog, which should give me the routes between two stations in a cycle. When I for example ask for the route between s3 and s4, it gives me the two correct routes [s3,s4] and [s3,s2,s1,s6,s5,s4], but it also gives me one solution I don't want. It is [s3,s4,s5,s6,s1,s2,s3,s4]. It shouldn't be possible to visit one station in one route several times. I tried to prevent this with the member command, but it seems it doesn't work always. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
% facts

connection(s1,s2).
connection(s2,s3).
connection(s3,s4).
connection(s4,s5).
connection(s5,s6).
connection(s6,s1).

% predicates

direction1(X,Y) :- connection(X,Y).
direction2(X,Y) :- connection(Y,X).

route1(X,Y,R):- route1(X,Y,[],R).
route1(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction1(X,Y).
route1(X,Y,L,R) :- direction1(X,Z), \+member(Z,L), route1(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ), R=[X|RZ].

route2(X,Y,R):- route2(X,Y,[],R).
route2(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction2(X,Y).
route2(X,Y,L,R) :- direction2(X,Z), \+member(Z,L), route2(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ), R=[X|RZ].

route(X,Y,R) :- route1(X,Y,R); route2(X,Y,R).
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic error in Prolog. You get this additional answer because the third rule of `route1` (or `route2`) matches with a superset of what matches with the second rule, which is not what you want.

For example, if we look only at:

```
route1(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- direction1(X,Y).
route1(X,Y,L,R) :- direction1(X,Z), \+member(Z,L), route1(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ), R=[X|RZ].
```

Then we see that if `X` and `Y` match the first rule, then they will also match the second rule, leading to your problem. Indeed, we want the second rule to only apply if the first rule failed (i.e. if there is not already a path between `X` and `Y` and that we have to go through other points starting from `Z`).

Therefore we can fix this problem with those simple changes (after removing the call to `member`):

```
route1(X,Y,R) :- 
    route1(X,Y,[],R).
route1(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- 
    direction1(X,Y).
route1(X,Y,L,R) :- 
    \+ direction1(X,Y), 
    direction1(X,Z), 
    route1(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ), 
    R=[X|RZ].

route2(X,Y,R) :- 
    route2(X,Y,[],R).
route2(X,Y,_,[X,Y]) :- 
    direction2(X,Y).
route2(X,Y,L,R) :- 
    \+ direction2(X,Y), 
    direction2(X,Z), 
    route2(Z,Y,[Z|L],RZ), 
    R=[X|RZ].
```

With the two lines in bold, we say that those rules apply only if there is not already a direct path between `X` and `Y`.